# How to understand a way to get around MyISAM FK issue?

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

Good day everyone.

(I'm a vet finishing up my 2 year associates degree in web/software development this semester and have chosen to help a local non-profit to help me learn and help them function.)

I'm producing for them a volunteer database but they are limited to shared hosting and MyISAM unfortunately is a requirement.

To be frank, my brain is on the fritz with this problem. I've been taught off and on the last two years that basically ACID = SQL (well, you know, the goal of ACID should be used in any DB implementation.)

The following is a sample DB table I'm trying to create and use:

```
Table: log
pk: pid
fk: task.pid
fk: volunteer.pid
```

Well, I just learned tonight, that MyISAM doesn't allow foreign keys. I'm really kind of freaking out now heh. I don't even know how to tackle this and go from here. Is there any way at all possible I can reference the same volunteer for both log table and task table?

The goal is:

- Administrator would login to the admin console.
- Then click on a list of volunteers that have been populated on the screen.
- Display all latest tasks completed by said volunteer.

Is this possible on MyISAM?

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can manually assign the key when you write or update the table row. It's not great but that's MyISAM

Comment: Hmm. So I would first call an SQL getting the intended volunteer then use that in a following SQL statement?

Comment: can you share the reason that they can't use INNODB?

Comment: They are using Lunarpages, a shared hosting provider. They are a non-profit barely making the ends meet at the moment so any additional funds would be too much and they don't want to leave providers. Lunarpages only allows InnoDB on their corporate accounts. Shared hosting requires MyISAM (due to increase server resource usage.)

Comment: you can call the details using `JOIN`, depending on what you actually want to do with said keys, but the writing of the contents of that table would be more manual. RE: InnoDB I ask because all the hosting providers I've come across provide several types of engine, so you can usually choose MyISAM or INNODb or a couple of others I dont remember.

Comment: I appreciate that. At least I now have a way to wrap my head around a solution. Just need to grab the SQL first for volunteer in any call then another SQL call with that volunteer. @Martin they only allow MERGE type or MyISAM. I've gone in and looked myself.

Comment: One small additional question, and I realize it's sidebar, but would be ok, ethically or security-wise to include that id # in a php  variable?

Comment: All you need to do is add some SQL to manually enter the task and volunteer id's when editing or updating that data.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much.

Comment: depends entirely what you do with the PHP variable, but probably not. PHP variables as a rule shouldn't be public facing much,

Comment: @BluTiger I think you are maybe misunderstanding MyISAM's limitation. It supports foreign keys, pretty much any tabular database can; it just doesn't provide any internal enforcement (or CONSTRAINTs) of the keys specified by the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key feature of the relational model is that tuples (rows) are *related* to each other by *common value(s)* stored in columns.

In that sense, MyISAM supports relationships between rows.

So, to answer your question, yes, you can have multiple rows that have the same value in a column.

So, get the list of volunteers...

```
SELECT v.pid, v.name FROM volunteer v ORDER BY v.name

pid  name
---  ------
43   Barney
24   Fred
```

To display "all the latest tasks" for a given volunteer, assuming that's stored in the `log` table...

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.task_name
     , l.log_date
  FROM task t
  JOIN log l 
    ON l.id = t.log_id
 WHERE l.volunteer_id = 24 
 ORDER BY l.log_date DESC
```

---

MyISAM does *not* support declarative constraints to enforce integrity between the tables.

With InnoDB, you can ensure that no values get put into the `volunteer_id` column of the `log` table, when a matching row doesn't existin in the `volunteer` table. That is, a row with a matching value in the `id` column of the `volunteer` table. If you attempted to do that with InnoDB tables with a FOREIGN KEY constraint, InnoDB (MySQL) would return an error.

What MyISAM lacks is this kind of *enforcement* of `FOREIGN KEY` **constraints**.  MyISAM will let that INSERT/UPDATE be performed. MyISAM  doesn't care if there's a matching row or not.

If you need to enforce integrity in the database with MyISAM, that becomes an application responsibility. The application needs to check if a `volunteer_id` value to be stored in the `log` table is valid... whether that refers to a row in `volunteer` table, and decide whether it should continue the operation or stop.

But aside from that difference, the SQL would be the same, whether it's InnoDB or MyISAM.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I immediately went into panic mode thinking "is everything I learned in the last 2 years a lie?" :-)

Comment: In MyISAM, the FK clause is ignored; in InnoDB, it creates an implicit index (I think).  You still need the `INDEX`, but that can be done manually.